# Splitting and Saving Mp4 In Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mp4

So I want to make an application that will be able to split an mp4 into various segments and save them as separate videos, but I am having trouble with the approach to something like this. I can convert the mp4 into a byte array, but I am unable to properly trim or cut the bytes without the saved video being either corrupted or just not working. Is there a way to achieve this, either by using a byte array or by using another solution?
I know C# is not the best way to go about doing something like this, but it's my preferred coding language and I am trying to make an app only for myself, so I don't mind if the code is a bit messy or slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make an audio editor, it might be just better to use one like [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) (it is open source) or any other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that you can integrate into Unity without any third party dependencies, you can give this a try: https://github.com/jimm98y/SharpMp4Parser (disclaimer: I am the author). You can also find it here as a nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpMp4Parser/0.0.2-alpha. It is a C# port of the mp4parser from Java originally created by Sebastian Annies. It should be able to do what you wanted right inside Unity.